# ActiveMQ Backlog - Total Number of Waiting Messages

Tags: java, spring, activemq-classic

Is that possible to query the activemq for the total number of backlog messages programatically? I've researched on the same but unable to find enough details.

Answer (score 1):

I think the closest to your task is javax.jms.QueueBrowser. It allows to look at messages on a queue without removing them. A QueueBrowser can be created from a Session .

Answer (score 1):

You can use JMX to achieve what you are trying like given below.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20035519/1914051